# Accessing the middle of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In the following example, I'd like to move the dotted vertical lines to the (horizontal) center of the *arrows* connecting the lower elements. For example, the right dotted line should be centered with regard to the arrow connecting `l2` and `l3`. The best I could do is centering it *between the nodes* `l2` and `l3`, which looks bad since the arrows are of different length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, every path/.style={>=latex'}]

\node (h1) at (.5, 1) {$\{S1,S2\}$};
\node (h2) at (2, 1) {$\{S4\}$};
\node (l1) at (0, 0) {$\{S5, S6\}$};
\node (l2) at (1, 0) {$\{S5, S7\}$};
\node (l3) at (2, 0) {$\{S4\}$};    

\draw[->] (-.75, 1) -- (h1);
\draw[->] (h1) -- (h2);
\draw[->] (-.75, 0) -- (l1);
\draw[->] (l1) -- (l2);
\draw[->] (l2) -- (l3);

\draw[dotted] ($ (l2) !.5! (l3) $) to ++(90:1);
\draw[dotted] ($ (-.75,0) !.5! (l1) $) to ++(90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you give, the line is drawn at the midpoint between the centers of nodes `l2` and `l3`. One solution is to add a coordinate at the midpoint of the lower line between `l2` and `l3`, call it `l4`

```
...
\draw[->] (l2) -- (l3) coordinate[midway](l4);
\draw[dotted] (l4) to ++(90:1);
...
```

gives me a line halfway along the arrow between `{S5,S7}` and `{S4}`.
[image]

Comment: Use a `coordinate` instead of a `node`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah, you are correct. Updated.

Comment: Or, if you wish to keep the `node` syntax, use `node[coordinate,midway]`.

Comment: Just curiosity: why is `coordinate` better?

Comment: @rainer In my (limited) experience, the `coordinate` is better in this case because we don't intend to include any text at that position. If we did want to have text, we'd have to use a `node`. IMO, using a `coordinate` simplifies the code slightly and makes it obvious that its not a typo that there's no text at `l4`.

Comment: @darthbith: I see, thanks for the clarification!